# How to increase the font size of the request in postman tool?

Tags: css, fonts, postman

I am using Postman tool for hitting the REST api with request and response. I want to increase the font size of the request. Under Settings there seem to be just one option to increase the font size of the response but not for request.

How can the font size of the request be increased?

Answer (score 42):

Use `Ctrl + (key)` and `=+` (key, near to Backspace button). Press all keys at the same time.

It's working.

Comment: Bad solution; this increases the size of the entire UI.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: This is the only option I found to increase the size of the entire UI, but oddly enough in my keyboard, the key was = and not +

Answer (score 23):

You can change postman font in **Settings->User Interface->Editor Font Size(px)** option

[see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3M14.png)

Answer (score 13):

The old postman app is just another webpage underneath it all, so use control +

For version 3, they've changed it to launch as a chrome desktop app. You can use a trick to open the developer tools, and change the fonts, or anything else, as you see fit. With Postman open, open a new tab in Chrome, and go to **chrome://inspect/#apps**. If Postman is open, you should see it listed in that page. Click the **inspect** link under it. Then you'll be able to inspect the elements whose fonts are too small, and change them. I believe it's just the `input[type="text"].basic-text-input` CSS selector, where you'll want to disable/change the 1.3rem font-size rule.

Comment: I was using an old version of postman. I updated, and see what you mean. I'll update my answer with a solution that works for postman 3.

Comment: The `zoom in` keyboard shortcut works for me with Postman 4.10.3 with Chrome 56 on Mac. (`cmd`+`=` on mac)

Answer (score 9):

The reason you can't zoom with `ctrl++` is that you are probably using the plus key **in the numpad section of your keyboard**. You need to **use the plus key next to backspace key**.

[keyboard screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGQ9Q.png)

Comment: This is the answer!!  The UI and the font all increase in size. Works with Postman 5.4.1

Comment: This is THE answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Settings > UI size option to change the font size of the interface.

Comment: Thats the response

Comment: there is an option only for the response text size, not the UI text size

Answer (score 3):

Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> to increase the font size of postman.

Answer (score 2):

For MAC Users.

`Postman -> Preferences -> Settings -> Shortcuts`

Command + or Command -

[image]

Comment: Is this no longer working? Monterey `12.0.1`, Postman `9.8.2`

Answer (score 1):

For native client
Go to **Settings -> General -> User Interface -> Font size**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Top menu of Postman window: View → Zoom In / Zoom Out scales down the UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you install [postman launcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-launcher/igofndmniooofoabmmpfonmdnhgchoka), you will have a real web page like this:

[image]

You could change everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here worked for changing the UI font size in the version of Postman that I have, 4.7.0. This is quick and dirty but it worked:

1. Open `~\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop\4.7.0_0\js\requester.js`.
2. Replace all `font: 12px` with `font: 1.25rem` (or your REMs of choice).
3. Save and restart Postman.

Answer (score 0):

To improve the font size forever, you just open the file **"4.7.2_0/html/requester.html"** with your text editor and add this code at the end of the file before the close of the tag `</body>`

In my case: **C:\Users\Stepan\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop\4.7.2_0**

```
 <style> .editor.ace_editor { font-size: 18px !important; } </style>
```

Reopen the app/extension and enjoy :P

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on File
2. Go to Settings
3. There's a section for User Interface
4. Change the "Editor Font Size(px) to whatever value you want. I use 14. Seems big enough.
   [Postman Settings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmPD3.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Go to **C:\Users[User]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop\3.2.8_0\css\requester**, look for the style are you using in Postman, example "style.dark.css" and changue to 1.4rem:

```
  #body, #code-data {
  font-family: "PTMono", Consolas, Courier, monospace, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem; // change to 1.4rem }
```